# SSRS report Row grouping and average value for each group

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a report with a row grouping in a table. Now I want to add an avarage value for each group. E.g. there's a table with data on employees visiting an office:

Name  |  In                        |  Out

John  |  2012-10-30 04:49:35.000   |   2012-10-30 05:49:35.000
Mark  |  2012-10-30 04:69:35.000   |   2012-10-30 04:79:35.000
John  |  2012-12-15 04:49:35.000   |   2012-10-30 04:49:35.000

I've made a grouping in my report on Name and get amount of visits for each employee:

`Name  |   Visits

John  |   2

Mark  |   1`

Now a need to add a column with an avarege time each employee spent in the office.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding a time spent column in your query. Then you could use the AVG function in SSRS to get what you need. You could probably just do an average on in - out within SSRS, but I always try to do the least amount of work in SSRS in order to boost performance.